# Automatic rerun stage in case of node fault

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a set of nodes and it's possible for a node to go offline during a job executing. Is there a way to automate a stage rerunning on another node in this case?

Rerun the whole job is possible too, but is not the desired solution, because all stages I have are independent.

Comment: Have you checked what type of exception is thrown? For rerunning a stage you could simply put your stage body in retry(x) {} block. If node block is defined only for the code within the stage the whole build would be governed on master with only the node blocks on the slaves. (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: The type of the exception is `hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException`.
Does `retry(x){stage{}}` retry only on a fault and not always?
Is there a way to retry only in case of this particular exception?

Comment: It should always retry, the thing is, what do you want ;)? I see two ways here, either you gonna try{}catch{} for this particular exception and have a specific implementation of your own retry with it, or you could just use the generic retry step functionality and have those retried on all errors. Anyway, to be more specific I would have to see your pipeline code.